# how to use a projector with Lubuntu 13.10

Tags: lubuntu, 13.10, 32-bit

My teacher has an Lubuntu 13.10 Laptop and he needs to use it on his projector, but there is no signal. Does anyone know how to use a projector in Lubuntu 13.10? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So far using ARandR has been the best option for me. Just install it using Synaptic (I don't use the Software Center so I don't know about it) and you can set just about anything. 
This here http://www.lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-screencast-multi-monitor-tips-tricks will give you ideas too.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.